# Add additional shipping fee using observer when customer after chose the shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'm tyring to add a additional cost to a shipping price after customer picked a shipping option (custom made shipping method), the event is base on checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method, here is my observer

```
public function saveShippingMethod($evt){

    $request = $evt->getRequest();
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    $pickup = $request->getParam('shipping_pickup',false);
    $quote_id = $quote->getId();
    $data = array($quote_id => $pickup);
    if($pickup){
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setPickup($data);

    }
    $carriers = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
    $selected_method = $request->getParam('shipping_method',false);
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setSelectedMethod($selected_method);
    foreach($carriers as $_rate) {
        if ($_rate->getCode() == $selected_method) {
            $current_price = $_rate->getPrice();
            $_rate->setPrice($current_price + 30);
            $_rate->save();
            $quote->save();
        }
        //echo $_rate->getCode()."<br>";
    }
    //var_dump($selected_method);
    //die();
}
```

but the above code is not successful, the new price is not showing in order review option, it is also not added after the order was saved.

*********update***********
i also try this but also the same

```
public function saveShippingMethod($evt){

        $request = $evt->getRequest();
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $pickup = $request->getParam('shipping_pickup',false);
        $quote_id = $quote->getId();
        $data = array($quote_id => $pickup);
        if($pickup){
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setPickup($data);

        }
        //$carriers = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
        $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $selected_method = $request->getParam('shipping_method',false);
        //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setSelectedMethod($selected_method);
        if($address->getAddressType()=='shipping') {
            $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                         ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
            foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
                foreach($carrier as $_rate) {
                    if ($_rate->getCode() == $selected_method) {
                        $current_price = $_rate->getPrice();
                        $_rate->setPrice($current_price + 30);
                        $_rate->save();
                    }

                }
            }
            $this->collectTotals($quote,$current_price + 30,$selected_method);
        }

        $quote->collectTotals();
        //$quote->save();
        //var_dump($selected_method);
        //die();
    }
    public function collectTotals($quote,$price,$shippingcode){
        $quoteid=$quote->getId(); 
        $shippingcode=$shippingcode;
        if($quoteid) {                    
                try{

                $quote->setSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingcode)/* ->collectTotals() */->save();
                $quote->save();
                foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

                    $address->setSubtotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                    $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                    $address->collectTotals();

                    $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                    $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );

                    $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

                    $address->setShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->save();
                }

                    $response['message'] = 'Succcess';
                } catch (Exception $e) {            
                        Mage::logException($e);
                        $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                 }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i just found the shipping_amount and base_shipping_amount was resumed to normal in DB after payment step was finished, anyone know why?

Comment: In app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php , the savePayment method line $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);, this line is setting my observer, how to solve that?

Comment: except rewrite the onepage